# Shortcut to defining the columns of a CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have this simple table:

```
create table t(x int, y int);
insert into t(x, y)
values
  (1,2),
  (2,3)
```

I wish to create a CTE which pulls in all of the columns from `t` and then adds its own column. I don't want to manually type out all of the columns of `t`. Can I do something like this?

```
with cte(t.*, z) AS(
  select
    t.*,
    1
  from t
)

select * from cte  -- ERROR:  syntax error at or near "." LINE 1: with cte(t.*, z) AS(
```

Comment: Please read the wiki or hint for the SQL tag, which strongly recommends that you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax between them varies. Knowing which DBMS you're using helps get answers for you more quickly, and doesn't waste the time of people who answer only to find out it won't work on your DBMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Just do:

```
with cte AS (
      select t.*, 1 as z
      from t
     )
. . .
```

When defining a CTE, you don't have to list the column names separately from the `select`.  It will use the column names in the CTE.